# Scikit Learn Predicting a Single Observation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

This is probably a really stupid question, but why do the following give different results?

```
X == array([  7.84682988e-01,   3.80109225e-17,   8.06386582e-01,
             1.00000000e+00,   5.71428571e-01,   4.44189342e+00])

model.predict_proba(X)[1] # gives array([ 0.35483244,  0.64516756])
model.predict_proba(X[1]) # gives an error
model.predict_proba(list(X[1])) # gives array([[ 0.65059327,  0.34940673]])
```

`Model` is a `LGBMClassifier` from the lightgbm library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets break it into simple steps to analyse:

1) `model.predict_proba(X)[1]`

This is equivalent to

```
probas = model.predict_proba(X)
probas[1]
```

So this first outputs the probabilities of all classes for all samples. So lets say your X contains 5 rows and 4 features, with two different classes.

So probas will be something like this:

```
            Prob of class 0,   prob of class 1  
For sample1         [[0.1,            0.9],
For sample2          [0.8,            0.2],
For sample3          [0.85,           0.15],
For sample4          [0.4,            0.6],
For sample5          [0.01,           0.99]]
```

`probas[1]` will just output the probabilities for second column of your `probas` output, ie. probability of class 1.

```
Output [0.9,     0.2,   0.15,       0.6,       0.99]
```

Other two lines of code depend on the implementation and version of how to handle single dimension array. For eg. scikit v18 only shows a warning for it and considers it as a single row. But v19 (master branch) throws an error.

**EDIT: Updated for LGBMClassifier**

2) `model.predict_proba(X[1])`

This is equivalent to:

```
X_new = X[1]
model.predict_proba(X_new)
```

Here you are selecting only the second row which results in a shape `[n_features, ]`. But LGBMClassifier require 2-d data to be of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`. This can be a possible source of error as mentioned above. You can reshape the given array to have 1 in place of n_samples:

`model.predict_proba(X[1].reshape(1, -1))`  # Will work correctly

3) `model.predict_proba(list(X[1]))`

This can be broken into:

```
X_new = list(X[1])
model.predict_proba(X_new)
```

This is also mostly same as 2nd, just that the `X_new` is now a list instead of numpy array, and automatically handled as a single row (same as `X[1].reshape(1, -1)` in 2nd case), instead of throwing an error.

So considering the example above, the output will be only,

```
For sample2          [0.8,            0.2],
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still puzzled about why #3 gives a different answer to #1 though.

Comment: @ndrue Because they are two different quantities. First is the only the proababilities of class 1 (in a class 0, class 0, class 2 ...) for all your test data  X. Third is the probabilities of all classes for second row (index 1, only one row) of your data. I have edited the answer to include example.